# How to add iOS 16 beta 8 (20A5358a) to Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, beta, ios16

I have today downloaded and installed Xcode 14 which comes with iOS 16 beta 5 (20A5339d) as an installed platform. However I want to test my app using the simulator against the latest beta 8 (20A5358a). How do I go about downloading/installing beta 8 as a new platform in Xcode?

I've tried clicking the '+' button in Preferences->Platforms, but that only allows adding iOS versions 15.5 and earlier.